# phantomjs-node rendering blank screenshots

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, phantomjs

I am trying to run a phantom script using phantomjs-node. The function is called correctly the file 'schemas.png' downloads correctly, but it is blank. It's like phantom isn't able to locate anything on the page, because I tried passing in the id of the element it should capture to the getElementBounds function and it came back as undefined, so I hard-coded in the clipRect boundaries just to test it out. Is there a step I'm missing, like making it wait for the page to load or something? (By the way I'm testing this on my local host).
Here is my complete code:

```
phantom.create(function (ph) {
      ph.createPage(function (page) {
        page.viewportSize = {
          width: 1600,
          height: 1200
        };
        page.open(pageUrl, function (status) {
            setTimeout(function () {
              // var clipRect = module.exports.getElementBounds(page, 'designer');
              var clipRect;
              var getElementBounds = function (id) {
                return page.evaluate(function (id) {
                  clipRect = document.getElementById('designer').getBoundingClientRect();
                  return {
                    top: clipRect.top,
                    left: clipRect.left,
                    width: clipRect.width,
                    height: clipRect.height
                  };
                }, id);
              };
              // page.clipRect = getElementBounds('designer');
              page.clipRect = {
                bottom: 421.81817626953125,
                height: 350,
                left: 0,
                right: 640,
                top: 71.81817626953125,
                width: 640
              };
              console.log("Capturing designer");
              page.render('schemas.png');
              ph.exit();
            }, 100);
        });
      });
    });
```

Comment: Have you checked that the page is successfully opened? You could `page.render` the whole page to check that. Also why not set [page.onError](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html) callback to see if anything went wrong?

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-3_phantomnodeerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: that worked for me, thanks! @ArtjomB.

Comment: It was an ssl issue with d3 (https) so I loaded the library locally rather than via the url and it resolved the issue @ArtjomB.

Comment: I see. Keep in mind that PhantomJS and phantom are different in many ways. The code you've given here is not work in node.js

Comment: +1 to ArtjomB's last comment. In phantomjs-node (a.k.a. phantom), the ssl flags are passed into the module's create function like so: phantom.create("--web-security=no", "--ignore-ssl-errors=yes", function (ph) { ... instead of in the command line for PhantomJS. And the render viewport is instantiated using page.set('viewportSize', {width:1200,height:900}) instead of page.viewport in PhantomJS.

Comment: I don't know how relevant this is to the problem but i notice you are declaring both a top and bottom property to clipRect.  Seems redundant and error prone.